# How can I put a less-than symbol into a ChoiceFormat pattern?

Tags: java, internationalization, struts

I have a message I'd like to throw into an HTML page, and I'd like it to be sensitive to the number of things bring printed. `java.text.ChoiceFormat` to the rescue, right?

```
text.messages=You have {0,choice,1#<b>one</b> message|1<<b>{0}</b> messages} waiting for you
```

This result in an error in the `ChoiceFormat`'s constructor:

> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Choice Pattern incorrect: 1#<b>one</b> message|1<'<b>'{0}'</b>' messages
> ```

I've narrowed-down the problem to the `<` symbol in the message. No problem: I'll use `MessageFormat`'s quoting capabilities to fix that:

```
text.messages=You have {0,choice,1#'<b>'one'</b>' message|1<'<b>'{0}'</b>' messages} waiting for you
```

Unfortunately, this also fails:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Choice Pattern incorrect: 1#<b>one</b> message|1<''<b>''{0}''</b>'' messages
> ```

Note how the single-quote characters (escape characters for `MessageFormat`) are doubled in the error message. I feel like I'm close, but I can't seem to find any documentation that explains how to use special characters like `<` in a `ChoiceFormat` pattern.

Here's the full stack trace I get when this fails:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Choice Pattern incorrect: 1#''<b>''one''</b>'' message|1<''<b>''{0}''</b>'' messages
        at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1519)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362)
    at org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources.getMessage(MessageResources.java:305)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.struts.MessageTool.get(MessageTool.java:158)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.struts.MessageTool.get(MessageTool.java:125)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.struts.MessageTool.get(MessageTool.java:192)
[...]
```

Comment: I'm okay with the vote to close, but I do think the answer has some utility. I'm happy to re-work the question so that both it and the answer is better-suited to the SO format, with a question about how to get characters requiring escaping to work with Struts resource bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but didn't quote all of them:

```
text.messages=You have {0,choice,1#'<b>'one'</b>' message|1<'<b>'{0}'</b>' messages} waiting for you
```

Or:

```
text.messages=You have {0,choice,1#'<b>one</b> message'|1<'<b>'{0}'</b> messages'} waiting for you
```

Comment: Actually, this was a contrived example, changed to protect the guilty. The missing single-quotes are a typo in the question. I'll update the question accordingly. In the real code, all escapes are in place.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Well, both examples I made works, and your own error message says that you didn't quote the first set, so please try again.

Comment: Hmm. I wrote a driver wrapped-around this example and it does in fact work. There is another layer at work in between the resource bundle and the `MessageFormat` in my application: Apache Velocity Tools. Perhaps those doubled quote-characters are an indication that something is being modified somewhere along the way.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't produce an SSCCE before posting... I could have saved us all some time. This is clearly not a problem with Java's `ChoiceFormat` but with the configuration of my own complex environment. Thanks for the answer: it definitely got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Struts 1.x "helpfully" escapes single-quotes in resource bundles... presumably so that a stray single-quote will not break `MessageFormat`. Here's the revision that implemented it:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=48526

This escaping can be disabled, but it must be done on a per-MessageResources-basis:

```
<message-resources key="MyProperties" parameter="MyProperties">
  <set-property property="escape" value="false" />
</message-resources>
```

If you wanted to have some properties that are escaped and others that are not, you could easily use a trick like this:

```
<message-resources key="MyProperties" parameter="MyProperties">
  <set-property property="escape" value="false" />
</message-resources>
<message-resources key="MyPropertiesEscaped" parameter="MyPropertiesEscaped">
  <set-property property="escape" value="true" />
</message-resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called "escape sequences/characters". In HTML, you would replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

Though I don't recall the `<` needing to be escaped in Java, you would put a backslash `\` before a character in Java to escape it.

Hope this helps!

Escape tables:

For [Java](http://javajee.com/escape-sequences-in-java-with-examples)

For [HTML](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119)

Comment: Sorry, this won't work: I need those tags to actually work. Java properties won't automatically un-HTML-escape values.

Comment: Then please clarify your question, as it is very unclear. You tag Java and talk about HTML. I gave you a Java answer. Include in your question what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: It's *very* clear that I'm talking about HTML in a page. Re-read the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag HTML? Because right now, you've got mostly Java users looking at this. If you tag both, it will pop out to the people that know both.

Comment: I don't need help with HTML. I need help with some Java component. Forget HTML: how can I get a `<` into my output? `&lt;` is not acceptable.

Comment: Well, edit the question so that you don't have to type that in the comments. And please add a bit more code so the problem can be recreated/understood. Also, please show the output and the desired output.